# Get Help in command line of R

Tags: r

In R, one does `?plot` in order to get help for the `plot`.

Is there a way to get help in command line for the internal structures of the language, for example, about variable function arguments '...', different type of array access `[]` or `[[]]`, `$`, etc ?

```
> help("...")
No documentation for ‘...’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??...’
```

Comment: ```?'['``` , help about function arguments is found in the help for the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For indexing functions, you can use :

```
help("[")
```

This works because `[`, for example, is in fact a function by itself, as you can see if you do :

```
x <- 1:5
do.call("[", list(x, 2))
[1] 2
```

Whereas `...` is not a function, so `help("...")` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, quote the function name in backticks

```
?`[`.
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `?'$'`, `?'['`? It works for me.